# Readjusting watermarks on Flink

Tags: stream, apache-flink

I take that watermarks can be adjusted in 2 ways:

- by emitting them via SourceContext.emitWatermark() on the datasource
- by wiring a WatermarksStrategy to the DataSourceStream

Would I be emitting watermarks already in a datasource, if I wire a new Watermark strategy after the datasource operator, will the first watermarks be replaced by the ones of the late watermark strategy?

Essentially I'm in a situation where I don't have control over the source-events/datasource, but I would need to later adjust the watermarks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a WatermarkStrategy at any point in a Flink pipeline. A downstream watermark generator will eat any incoming watermarks -- the only watermarks it emits will be those it generates. Moreover, it's not necessary that the source generate watermarks (though it is preferable).